# Debezium Connector doesn't track MySql database changes

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm currently testing a Kafka Cluster to be connected to a Mysql server to track its changes with with the Debezium Connector available for Kafka Connect.

I've been given a Mysql test server with read-only permission to perform some tests but the frequency of which this server is being updated leaves a lot to be desired, so I installed MySql on my workstation, created a new user and gave it the necessary permissions, and created a database called `mysql`*`test` *inside of which I created a table called `test_table` .

This is the connector's config that I'm using:

```
{
    "name": "debezium-local-test-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "localhost",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "kafka",
        "database.password": "thepassword",
        "database.server.id": "1",
        "topic.prefix": "mysql_test",
        "table.include.list": "test_table",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.boostrap.servers": "10.4.90.30:9092",
        "schema.history,internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory.mysql_test"
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "database.connectionTimeZone": "Europe/Rome",
        "debezium.source.database.history": "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory",
        "debezium.source.database.history.file.filename": "path/to/db-history.dat",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbHistory.mysql_test",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "10.4.90.30:9092"

    }
}
```

The connector is able to connect to the Mysql server as it gets created and run succesfully but the `mysqltest` topic contains zero messages and any data that i INSERT into the `test_table` isn't being tracked.

Kafka Connect and the Mysql server are running on the same machine so having set the database hostname as "localhost" should be correct.

Keep in mind that I'm not able to copy-paste here the JSON file that contains Debezium's configuration so there might be a few typos on what I've written above as this question was all written by hand...

I've even tried to remove the  `"table.include.list"` parameter inside the JSON in order to follow the whole of the database to no avail.

EDIT: I noticed that, for some reason, the connector doesn't automatically create the topic specified in the `topic.prefix` field. This happens even if I copy/paste the configuration of the same connector that poins to the external MySql server instead.
According to the Kafka UI manager the local debezium connector runs but it has no topic associated to it.
The behaviour doesn't change even if I create the topic prior to the connector's creation.

Comment: For start, you should qualify `table.include.list` with database name : `test.test_table` . Also did you follow [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#setting-up-mysql)?. Adding snippet from your connect logs can also help

Comment: quoting: "I noticed that, for some reason, the connector doesn't automatically create the topic specified in the topic.prefix field." This is a topic prefix and not a topic name. Your topic should be called `mysql_test.test.test_table`  ([prefix].[database].[table])

Comment: After scouring the logs it turned out that Mysql wasn't set-up to write bin logs, and so the connector wouldn't attach itself to the topic. 
It begs the question of why Debezium wouldn't simply fail instead of being run but that's the way it is.